# checking input validity of directory

Tags: java, file-io, directory

If I have a folder C:\folder and I print out the following

```
File f = new File("C:\\folder");
System.out.println(f.exists() + " " + f.isDirectory() + " " + f.isAbsolute());
```

It will print out true true true if the folder exists.

but what I wish to do is check to see if a string is a directory as well as being absolute without the folder existing for example.
If I do not have a folder "C:\some non existent folder"
With the following code

```
File f = new File("C:\some non existent folder");
System.out.println(f.exists() + " " + f.isDirectory() + " " + f.isAbsolute());
```

This will output false false true 
so how would I be able to figure out if a string is a directory without it existing (I thought about using a regular expression but its too unreadable and could cause cross platform incompatibility)

Comment: You cannot do that, because a plain file named `"C:\some non existent folder"` can also be created

Comment: How can anything be a directory if it doesn't exist? It must exist in order to be a directory...